# Is Nanatsu No Taizai inspired from Ubel Blatt?

Tags: ubel-blatt, seven-deadly-sins

If you've read both manga, one could see that the two are quite similar. This similarity is not just limited to the characters but also as to how the story plays out (e.g. The Seven Deadly Sins and Lances of Betrayal).

Has there been any statement regarding this from any of the authors or staff working on the respective manga?

Or is it the case that this type of plotline is too common anyways?

Comment: These are not the only manga/anime to involve the Seven Deadly Sins. Other include: - Re: Zero kara hajimaru isekai seikatsu - Fullmetal Alchemist While it may seem similar, concepts of conspiracies to frame innocent are also a common occurence.

Comment: I read both, but besides a few overlaps on very rough concepts, like the ones you mention. I don't really think the stories are anything alike whatsoever.

Comment: @ManuelHoffmann there are more then a few overlaps. The OP ness of the MC, The main bad guy that seems is dead, turns out to be alive later etc. etc. The point of the question was that did either author work closely together to have these many similarities. It may be bias on my part, since it is known that sometimes similar stories are worked out independently, for example, White House Down and Olympus has Falled :x